# Data-bricks - SQL - SUM of years

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks-community-edition

I'm would like to get the SUM of each column by years. Rather then displays several individual rows for the same year.

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, 
useful, funny, cool
FROM reviews_without_text_table
ORDER by year ASC;
""").show(truncate=False)
```

[enter image description here][1]

Please view the attatchment here:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYIrA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, 
sum(useful) useful,sum(funny) funny,sum(cool) cool
FROM reviews_without_text_table
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
ORDER by year ASC;
""").show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: What would I have to change if I needed to find "Number of reviews per year"?

Comment: "Number of reviews per year" what you say I don't understand please tell me what you want. I was write answered that is year wise summary.